# ssrs exporting to excel as csv

Tags: excel, visual-studio, reporting-services

I am calling SSRS reports from an in house piece of software. All the reports made before me render as xlsx or xls and mine continuously are rendering as csv files which is messing up my formatting. Does anyone know how to address this?

Comment: check your config file on the report server. Might pay to turn the csv mode off for Excel rendering and then give it a go

Comment: @Harry when you say shout off the csv mode for Excel rendering is that something I need to do in Visual Studio or in the report server?

Comment: It's on the report server.. it's a config file that has all the settings for every export format there is. should be something like this on the report server.. the file name is : rsreportserver.config
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSRSXXXX.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services
ensure you back up the file before you make any changes

Comment: Thank you @Harry!!!

Comment: did it work for you.. turning off the csv mode?

Comment: I am an intern and don't have access to the report server in that manner. I did however pass the info on and found out that the dev server outputs csv but when I move to prod it will only output xlsx so I asked the question for nothing. I was just trying to work on my own and not bother people, thats what I get for that. Thank you anyways for your help, I still learned something new!!!